# Compile time localization on embedded scripting language

Tags: localization

I've been working on a project using a rather very unpopular scripting language called Sourcepawn. I'm currently in the need of localizing the current software. The script will always run on the same language, therefor I'm aiming for compile time localization, but all I've found are runtime solutions, and most of them can't be implemented. I've found https://github.com/pzavolinsky/baked-i18n but it's unmaintained and not compatible with current syntax for some reason.

The call syntax in Sourcepawn is identical to C, so I'm aiming I can do something like

```
printf(_t("Hello!"));
```

And after processing the text, get a result like this:

```
printf("Hola!");
```

And get it translated using an external file, much like the project I linked before that unfortunately doesn't work. Are there any solutions, perhaps some that try to be "language-agnostic" like the mentioned one, that can help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use translations in SourcePawn using `%T` and passing the translation key followed by the client index.

```
PrintToChat(client, "%T", "Hello", client);
```

https://wiki.alliedmods.net/Translations_(SourceMod_Scripting)